# How to delete a child in firebase but not the folder it is under?

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

I am using swift/google firebase and I have several values in a folder.  When i call the remove value statement, I want to delete a child not the folder.  PLease refer to my code.

```
 databaseRef.child("numbers").observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    databaseRef.child("numbers").child(self.TextField.text!).setValue(["thename" : UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "nametext")])

                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(self.therow) , execute: {

                            Database.database().reference().child("numbers").child(self.TextField.text!).removeValue()
                        })
```

The above code is saying that is creating a child node in the numbers folder then is supposed to delete it after a ceartin time (.seconds(self.therow).  The program is only supposed to delete the child node (self.TextField.text!), but it ends up deleting the entire folder "numbers".  I want the folder to stay but the child to delete.

Comment: what does the above code do? what is the error?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 check the updated question please

Comment: The issue was that when I ran a pop view controller command it erased the value of the text field so it could not accuratley delete the child, I fixed this by creating a variable before the pop view controller command.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the last value from a location, the path is automatically removed.
This is how firebase works.